# how can i confirm _JAVA_OPTS is being enforced?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I set the environment variable like this `_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g"` does that ensure that all java apps will use that setting?

How can I confirm that global setting is in effect?

Is this just for java apps that don't explicitly set this or can apps override this if they set that manually when starting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

- Try `jps -lv`, which list java process with arguments passed to it.
- If that don't show the vm args, then try `jcmd 12793 VM.flags`, and replace the pid with your pid.

Comment: is there a way I can jcmd to a container? It can't seem to attach to it (jmap neither). I tried to docker exec another bash terminal in order to connect

Comment: @red888 I am not sure, you can refer to this http://trustmeiamadeveloper.com/2016/03/18/where-is-my-memory-java/